# How to keep the loaded Chrome extension after ChromeDriver session ends?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, debugging, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, facebook-php-webdriver

I need to install an extension to pre-existing profile for debugging. But ChromeDriver installs extensions in the temp folder and they disappear after the session ends. Can I somehow install the extension in the origin profile folder to keep it? Thanks!